# Not able to get spreadsheet values. Error code: 403, The request is missing a valid API key

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Sorry I'm trying to figure out how to use Google Sheet apis.
I am getting the required output on the google developers site but not getting when I try to open it in another tab.
[image]

[image]

Sorry for the stupid question, if you could help me that would be great!
Thanks!

Expected to get the values of the spreadsheet. Got:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the first image, your access token is passed in the request, when you open the URL in a new tab, this is not added. You cannot make the same request directly from a new tab you might have to use sort of code for the same. Thus, when you open the URL in a new tab you are unauthenticated and get this issue.

Check the ways to authorize your request in the reference below.

#### Reference:

- [Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing)